# BigQuery wildcard tables - what are the limits?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm thinking about organizing a BigQuery dataset with multiple tables that I can query using wildcards.

In this use case, there will potentially be 1000+ tables, each one representing a different customer. I need to be able to query them individually, and I also need to query them all at the same time.

I'm thinking of using multiple tables rather than a single table with clustering, because, when running queries only for specific customers, I would like to be able to scan only the data that I need.

The [Quotas and limits](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas) page lists the following limits that look applicable:

- Maximum number of tables referenced per query — 1,000
- Maximum resolved legacy and standard SQL query length — 12 MB
- The limit on resolved query length includes the length of all views and wildcard tables referenced by the query.

My questions are:

1) When running a query with wildcard (such as `` SELECT * FROM `project_id.dataset_id.table_*` ``), do all the individual tables that match the wildcard get counted against this 1000 tables limit?

2) What exactly is counted against the 12 MB limit? For example, suppose I have the following tables `project_id.dataset_id.table_1`, `project_id.dataset_id.table_2`, `project_id.dataset_id.table_3`.

- If I run a SELECT on `table_*`, what will constitute the resolved query length? Does it include the fully qualified name of all tables (`project_id.dataset_id.table_1`, `project_id.dataset_id.table_2`, `project_id.dataset_id.table_3`)?
- If I use the wildcard `table_*` but include a filter on `_TABLE_SUFFIX` (for example, `WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX = "1"`), does this eliminate tables that don't match the filter from the resolved query?

3) Are there any other limitations that I should be aware of?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

My advice is against. You will quickly reach 1000 tables and than you cannot query them all. The other is that having each table separately it will be unmaintainable.

You can use clustering to your help. 
If one of your columns is the `tenant_id` than you can use that in clustering.

Comment: Thank you, I'm thinking of using partitioning on time + clustering on a customer ID field. My concern with clustering is that there seems to be no way to predict what the efficiency will be when data grows and there are many clients with very different data volumes. Is there any way to make predictions on how much will be scanned?

Comment: Read about 'dryrun' concept, that might help getting some predictions.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, it seems like, for clustered tables, dry runs only show an upper bound (the same value as if there was no clustering). In this use case I would like to be able to estimate how much it will cost to retrieve data for a single customer, so that the cost of providing this to a customer is well known based on the customer's data volume.

Comment: I suggest you to raise a [Feature Request](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=1162659) asking about this functionality also vote and supply feedback about how it would be useful.

Answer (score 2):

> When running a query with wildcard, do all the individual tables that match the wildcard get counted against this 1000 tables limit?

All tables that match wildcard and _TABLE_SUFFIX filter will count against 1000 limit

> What exactly is counted against the 12 MB limit?

Length of fully qualified names of all tables counted against above explained 1000 tables limit will be counted against 12 MB limit

> Are there any other limitations that I should be aware of?

Suggestion - combination of partitioning and clustering will serve you much better in use case you describe in your question. Especially that now you can partition by [integer range](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-integer-range-partitions)
This will give your superior flexibility in maintaining and processing data to compare with sharded tables approach
Obviously, there are still [limitations related to partitioned tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#partitioned_tables) to consider

Comment: Thank you, I'm thinking of using partitioning on time + clustering on a customer ID field. My concern with clustering is that there seems to be no way to predict what the efficiency will be when data grows and there are many clients with very different data volumes. Is there any way to make predictions on how much will be scanned?